# MERGE INTO and CONCATENATION

Tags: sql, merge, concatenation, teradata

So, I'm not sure why this statement isn't working in Teradata.

```
MERGE INTO table1 as a
USING table2 as b
ON a.date = b.date AND a.id = b.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET col2 = CAST(a.col2 as VARCHAR(3)) ||','|| CAST(b.col2 as VARCHAR(3))
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, col2, date)
    VALUES (b.id, b.col2, b.date);
```

I'm trying to concatenate column 2 when both id and date match from each table.  The statement executes with no errors, however, the concatenation portion isn't working even though there are several date/id matches.  I'm not sure why it isn't.

Any suggestions?

Comment: the join is on date and id. what do you mean by `col1/col2` matches?

Comment: My mistake edit made.

Comment: Is the table defined as SET or MULTISET? Is the PI defined as unique or non-unique? Is col2 empty for the records where there is a match?

Answer (score 0):

From your query,

```
UPDATE SET col2 = CAST(a.col2 as VARCHAR(3)) ||','|| CAST(b.col2 as VARCHAR(3))
```

I assume your col2 is varchar(3) and that could be the issue.

If your data is already 3 character and your column is varchar(3)...

Assuming 3 chars in the original data:

To run this query once, you need a size of at least 7 chars for the column.

To run this query periodically, you need a very high field size and change the query to

```
UPDATE SET col2 = a.col2 ||','|| CAST(b.col2 as VARCHAR(3))
```

Not sure if the casting actually has any functional implication on your requirement.